# Get id's retrieved by data attribute using javascript from li items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**JavaScript**

---

```
var sessions = [];
$('.rightDiv').each(function(index) {
    var session = $.trim($(this).text().slice(0, -1)).split("×");
    var sessionData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < session.length; i++) {
        var ids = $(this).find('li').data('id');
        var s = {
            subjectOrder: i,
            subjectID: ids
        };
        sessionData.push(s);
    }
    var ses = {
        sessionNo: index,
        sessionData: sessionData
    };
    sessions.push(ses);
});
```

**HTML**

---

```
 <ul id="form_builder_sortable_sample" class="sortable rightDiv session4 ui-sortable"> 
  <li class="draggable" data-id="1" name="Counting" >Counting<button onclick="deleteElement(event)" class="delbtn">×</button></li>
  <li class="draggable" data-id="2" name="Priorities" >Priorities" class="delbtn">×</button></li>
 </ul>
```

**JSON**

---

```
{"sessionNo":"0","sessionData":[{"subjectOrder":"0","subjectID":"1"},{"subjectOrder":"1","subjectID":"1"}]}
```

**My Problem**

---

What the code above does, is retrieves the session no from the ul class: `class="sortable rightDiv session4"` and each id of the li from `data-id`.

In this case it loops fine through the `li` items, but it only displays the id of the first `li` element. 
It should be:

```
{"sessionNo":"0","sessionData":[{"subjectOrder":"0","subjectID":"1"},{"subjectOrder":"1","subjectID":"2"}]}
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `$(this).find('li').data('id');`, it will always return the value of first `li` data attribute.

Use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/#jQuery-each-array-callback) to iterate and create an array

```
var sessionData = [];

$(this).find('li').each(function (index, elem) {
    sessionData.push({
        subjectOrder: index,
        subjectID: $(elem).data('id')
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
var ids  = $(this).find('li').data('id');
```

to:

```
var ids  = $(this).find('li').eq(i).data('id');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it helps to clear it our, but I will be accepting Saptal answer :)

Comment: is it working ? just a quick fix if you in deadline =))